# A tricky integral equation

Tags: integration, integral-transforms, expectation

In the context of reconstruction of climate data from ice cores (see related [question at MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4316129/accuracy-of-the-radiocarbon-method-from-a-mathematical-point-of-view)) I came about the following problem. (More background and motivation can be given on demand.)

---

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an arbitrary smooth function, and let $p(x)$ be a probability function with $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x)\text{d}x = 1$. We can write:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ p(x)\ \text{d}x = f\Big( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ p(x) \ \text{d}x  \Big) + \epsilon$$

My question is for the error $\epsilon$. Can there be a closed form or an estimation of lower and upper bounds in terms of $f$ and $p$? Which mathematical techniques do I have to apply?

---

There are some extreme cases where an exact solution is easy to obtain:

(1) $f(x) \equiv x_0$. In this case we have

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x_0\ p(x)\ \text{d}x = x_0 \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\ p(x) \ \text{d}x = x_0$$

which yields $\epsilon = 0$.

(2) $f(x) = \alpha x$. In this case we have

$$\alpha \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ p(x)\ \text{d}x = \alpha\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ p(x) \ \text{d}x  + \epsilon$$

which again yields $\epsilon = 0$.

(3) $p(x) = \delta(x)$. In this case we have for the left-hand side

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ \delta(x)\ \text{d}x = f(0)$$

and for the right-hand side

$$f\Big(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\ \delta(x)\ \text{d}x\Big) = f(0)$$

which again yields $\epsilon = 0$.

(4) [omitted]

---

Instead of the general case, I would also be happy with solutions for the next most simple cases:

(5) $f(x) = x^2$

(6) A normal distribution, essentially

$$p(x) = e^{-x^{2}}$$

Again: Which techniques should be applied to calculate or estimate the error $\epsilon$?

Comment: By Jensens inequality we know $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) p(x) \, dx \geq f\left( \int_\mathbb{R} x p(x) \, dx \right)$ for all convex functions $f$ and $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x) p(x) \, dx \leq f\left( \int_\mathbb{R} x p(x) \, dx \right)$ for all concave functions $f$. Suppose the support of $p$ is some Interval $I=[a,b]$ with $a \geq b$, then Jensens inequality also tells us, that we have equality if and only if $f$ is linear on $I$. This explains (1), (2) and (3) and might indicate, that bounding the second derivative of $f$ might help.

Comment: You can rewrite this with the expectation operator as $\epsilon = E[f(X)]-f(E[X])$. Then case 5 gives $\epsilon$ equal to the variance of $X$, and cases 5 and 6 together is the set-up for the delta method.

Comment: An interesting case is $f(x)=e^{tx}$ giving $\epsilon=M(t)-e^{t\mu}$ where $M(t)$ is the moment generating function and $\mu=E(X)$. If we relax $f(x)$ to be complex valued and set $f(x)=e^{ix\lambda}$ we get $\epsilon=\kappa(\lambda)-e^{i\lambda\mu}$ being $\kappa(\lambda)$ the characteristic function for density $p(x)$. I think these relationships can provide some insight about techniques to deal with this request.

Comment: Note that in this last case if we apply a properly normalized Fourier Inverse Transform we get $\epsilon(x)=f(x)-\delta(x-\mu)$ where $\int_\mathbb{R}\epsilon(x)dx=0$

Comment: *Can there be a closed form or an estimation of lower and upper bounds in terms of $f$ and $p$?* Erm... Isn't the *definition* of $\varepsilon$ a "closed form" in terms of $f$ and $p$? In general, if you want the expressions to be reasonably close, then you need to require that $f$ is nearly linear on almost all of the support of $p$ and that $f$ grows slower that $p$ decays on the tail part. Otherwise it is going to be a rather poor approximation...

Comment: @fedja: By "closed form" I mean a strongly and algebraically simplified expression for $\epsilon = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\ p(x)\ \text{d}x - f\Big( \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \ p(x) \ \text{d}x  \Big)$. I am mainly interested on which properties of $p$ and $f$ the error $\epsilon$ depends, e.g. the skewedness of $p$ or its deviation of the uniform distribution (to be defined somehow).

Comment: @fedja: Some sort of Taylor series for $\epsilon$ would be perfect - with the first three or four terms.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker If I understood you right in your MSE post, you mainly care about $f(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ and do not know anything about the true $p$, in which case I wonder what use is any formula with any assumptions if you know neither the parameters, nor whether the assumptions are satisfied. Also you care there about the multiplicative error, not about the additive one, right? Or is this a completely separate question that you want to use in some other context?

Comment: @fedja: Not quite right: In the MSE post $e^{\lambda t}$ came from radioactive decay and is a fixed and known function. The $f(t)$ in this MO post is a genuinely arbitrary function of time, e.g. the atmospheric concentration of carbon dioxide. That's why I gave the examples (1), (2), (4), (5).

Comment: @fedja: If I know neither the parameters nor whether the assumptions are satisfied, I have to perform Bayesian statistics. That's what I aim for.

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker *I have to perform Bayesian statistics*. Hmmm.... Interesting. Can you elaborate on how exactly? I'm sorry for my being so stupid, but your "arbitrary $f$" is not smooth or anything, so the Taylor approximation just doesn't seem appropriate to me. Also if I understand the idea of the Bayesian analysis right, I presume that $f$ is known and you try to determine $p$ by assuming some prior and then adjusting it by measuring something (what exactly?). The problem is that while I fancy that I understood your game in the MSE post, I am still completely in the dark here :-(

Comment: @fedja: Excuse me for not being explicit all the time, but when I said "arbitrary $f$" I meant "arbitrary but smooth $f$" - as I pointed out in the first sentence of my original post.

Comment: @fedja: Are you interested in a paper giving rather complete background on the reconstruction of climate data from ice cores and the underlying statistical model? When you read it you will better understand the background of my questions - and hopefully gain some interesting insights.